# Joining between multiple tables with LINQ is not showing accurate results

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have two main domain classes. Each domain class represents a table. These two domain classes has MANY-TO-MANY relationship. So I created another domain class to make ONE-TO-MANY relationship for both domain class. The domain classes are:

```
public class Child
    {
        public Child()
        {
            this.UserLog = new UserLog();
            this.ChildCares = new List<ChildCare>();
        }

        public Guid ChildId { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string BirthCountry { get; set; }
        public string CitizenCountry { get; set; }
        public string FatherSurname { get; set; }
        public string FatherFirstName { get; set; }
        public string FatherMiddleName { get; set; }
        public string MotherSurname { get; set; }
        public string MotherFirstName { get; set; }
        public string MotherMiddleName { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public virtual UserLog UserLog { get; private set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ChildCare> ChildCares { get; private set; }

public class Institute
    {
        public Institute()
        {
            this.UserLog = new UserLog();
            this.ChildCares = new List<ChildCare>();
        }

        public Guid InstituteId { get; set; }
        public string InstituteName { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
        public decimal AmountPerDay { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public UserLog UserLog { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ChildCare> ChildCares { get; private set; }
    }

public class ChildCare
    {
        public ChildCare()
        {
            this.UserLog = new UserLog();
            //this.Children = new Child();
            //this.Institute = new Institute();
        }
        public Guid ChildCareId { get; set; }
        public Guid ChildId { get; set; }
        public Guid InstituteId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public UserLog UserLog { get; set; }
        public virtual Child Children { get; set; }
        public virtual Institute Institute { get; set; }
```

The Child table has THREE rows. The Institute table has SIX rows. And the ChildCare table has THREE rows. No I want to select data by joining Child, Institute, ChildCare. As ChildCare class has both Child and Institute object. So I want to query from the ChildCare class. I want the Linq query to returns data as collection of following object, which is another domain class.

```
public class ChildDayCare
    {
        public string ChildrenName { get; set; }
        public string InstituteName { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public decimal ChargePerDay { get; set; }
    }
```

Now the query I written is given bellow.

```
public IList<ChildCare> GetAllChildrenCareAsList()
        {
            try
            {
                var childCareList = base.GetAll();
                var childCareArr = childCareList as ChildCare[] ?? childCareList.ToArray();
                return childCareArr.Any() ? childCareArr.ToList() : null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

var childCares = GetAllChildrenCareAsList();

            if (childCares != null)
            {

                IList<Child> children = childCares.Select(t => t.Children).ToList();
                IList<Institute> institutes = childCares.Select(t => t.Institute).ToList();

                var childDacareList = (from cc in childCares
                                       join cd in children on cc.Children.ChildId equals cd.ChildId
                                       join ins in institutes on cc.Institute.InstituteId equals ins.InstituteId
                                       select new ChildDayCare
                                       {
                                           ChildrenName = cd.MiddleName, //cd.FirstName + " " + cd.MiddleName + " " + cd.Surname,
                                           InstituteName = ins.InstituteName,
                                           StartDate = cc.StartDate,
                                           EndDate = cc.EndDate,
                                           ChargePerDay = ins.AmountPerDay
                                       }).ToList();

                return childDacareList;
            }
```

The query should show THREE rows. But instead It is showing 9 rows. Can anyone please tell me where I have done wrong.

Comment: why not try your query straight into entity?

Comment: plz give me an example

Comment: childCares.Include(t => t.Children).Include(t => t.Institute).ToList(); check if it returns all of the things you need

Comment: no, it's not working

Comment: what does it return?

Comment: childCares.Include - > it's showing error.

Comment: Add `using System.Data.Entity;` at the top of your file, then do the `.Include`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help:
IList institutes = children.Select(t => t.Institute).ToList();